# Why do SCNLights work on Apple's built in geometries, but not OBJ or DAE files?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, collada, scnnode

I've been struggling all day to get my SCNLights to work on my scene models. I have a SCNNode, with a SCNLight projecting a ".spot" type light in-game.

When I use Apple's built-in SCNBox and light the objects (orange in image), the lights are adjusted appropriately. However, when using my own model (the green grass), lighting is NOT appropriate whatsoever regardless of the bitmask used. How come? What do I need to change in my code so that my models respond to the bitmask appropriately?

I've tried it with OBJ, DAE, and SCN files (by going to Editor -> Convert to SceneKit file format), and they all produce the same problem. I first thought my bitmasks were the problem, but they work fine on apple's primitive models, but not mine.

---

[image: Orange Cuboids]
[image: Grass]

---

Code for the orange cuboids:

```
//These few lines sit in a class called "Tile," which contains an SCNNode called "grass"

let grassGeo = SCNBox(width: 0.3, height: 0.6, length: 0.3, chamferRadius: 0)
            grassGeo.materials.first!.diffuse.contents = UIColor.orange
            self.grass.geometry = grassGeo
            self.grass.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, 0)
            self.grass.categoryBitMask = Constants.bitMask.tile
            self.addChildNode(self.grass)
```

Code for grass model

```
self.grass = SCNNodeFromDAE(filePath: "testgame.scnassets/Models/t_grass/t_grass.dae")
            self.grass.scale = SCNVector3(1, 1, 1)
            self.grass.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, 0)
            self.grass.categoryBitMask = Constants.bitMask.tile
            self.addChildNode(grass)
```

Code for `SCNNodeFromDAE`:

```
func SCNNodeFromDAE(filePath: String) -> SCNNode {
        guard let s = SCNScene(named: filePath) else { fatalError("Failed to find DAE file.") }
        let n = SCNNode()

        for i in s.rootNode.childNodes {
            n.addChildNode(i as SCNNode)
        }

        return n
    }
```

---

UPDATE:
Per @Lock's suggestion, I've found that a light attached to my scene's camera is illuminating the nodes, however, I'm using bitmasks, which should give me the desired result. Am I not setting/using them correctly? Here is the camera setup code, and my bitmask struct in a file called "Constants:"

```
func setupCamera() {
    cam = SCNNode()
    cam.camera = SCNCamera()
    cam.eulerAngles = c.camAngle
    cam.light = SCNLight()
    cam.light!.type = .omni
    cam.light!.color = UIColor.white
    cam.light!.intensity = c.cam_l_intensity
    cam.light!.categoryBitMask = Constants.bitMask.usr //ONLY light the user
    scn.rootNode.addChildNode(cam)
}
```

And here is the bitmask code:

```
struct bitMask {
    static let usr:Int = 0x1 << 0 //1
    static let tile:Int = 0x1 << 1 //2
}
```

Comment: Could it be that your DAE file contains its own directional light?

Comment: There aren’t any light sources in the DAE itself. I intentionally removed them so I could manually apply light.

Comment: Interesting. In some situations SceneKit will automatically add lights. Looking at the images you posted I can see that the SceneKit directional light *is* lighting your grass nodes, it's just that there's another light in addition to the spot light that's lighting the nodes outside the spot light. I'd try writing a recursive function to iterate over your scene graph and check if any node has a light (apart from the spot light) after the scene is initialised/loaded.

Comment: @lock I've updated the question. It appears my camera light is illuminating the objects, but the bitmasks should accommodate. Am I not using/setting the masks accordingly?

Comment: Are the materials similar? Isn't one using `emission` or a different lighting model?